# How to get user's custom field information through mail?

Tags: shopify, klaviyo

I created a website form through "Klaviyo". So every data collected from that form get into Klaviyo software. but I want to get all the custom field data in my mail inbox. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the List the Form submits to triggers a Flow (e.g. Welcome Series), you can add a "Notification Action" in the flow that will send you an email each time someone signs up.

Example:
[image]

In Klaviyo, all Form values are added to the Profile as custom properties that you designate.  You can then reference those profile values in the subject/body of the message so that you see them in the message.